# Cntrl + . is not working for my VSCode pro writing a method

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code

I'm using VSCode 1.35 and trying to use shorthand for "writing method " in a .cs file like in Visual Studio and it does nothing.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.

There may be multiple "projects" in the folder and VSCode has selected the "wrong" one. (in VSCode terms "project" means the sln file)

Use ctrl-shift-P and select "OmniSharp: Select Project" to select the correct project (a .sln file).